# Command K_UP and K_DOWN not working in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have written the following code in my Pygame Program:-

```
if (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):

        x = player_pos[0]
        y = player_pos[1]

        if (event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
            x -= player_size
        elif (event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
            x += player_size
        elif (event.key == pygame.K_UP):
            y += player_size
        elif (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
            y -= player_size

        player_pos = [x,y]
```

But, when I press the up key the, object goes down and when I press the down key it goes up, while it should be vice-versa! Could anyone please let me know how can I fix this issue? Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pygame coordinate system, top left is (0, 0). From there the x-coordinates increase to the right and the y-coordinates increase downwards. Hence the y-axis points downwards. You need to decrement the y coordinate to move up and increment it to move down:

```py
elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
    y -= player_size
elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
    y += player_size
```

Comment: Ok I see! Thanks a lot for the help! Appreciate it!

Comment: And, for the x-axis, increment to go right and decrement to go left, right?

Comment: @Pressing_Keys_24_7 Yes. As  I mentioned, top left is (0, 0)

Answer (score 1):

the origin of the Descartes-like 2d coordinate system of pygame (and in general, computing) is the top left corner: (0, 0). from here, x and y increases towards the right and bottom, respectively